# Can't call main in other class

Tags: c#

I made a console application and I'm trying to call the main of the class `Template` from the `Program` class. In the `Program` class I've a menu switch like this:

```
int menu = 0;
while (menu != 7)
        {
            select = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (select)
            {
                case 1: 
                    new Template();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Bad choice!");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

this is the class `Template();`

```
 static void main(string[] args)
 {
        Console.WriteLine("Template");
        new Template().menu();
 }

 public void menu()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Menu Template opened!");
 }
```

the problem is that the main of `Template` isn't called, I also tried to put a break point on the line `new Template().menu();` but isn't fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating the `Template` class does not automatically execute the `main` function. In fact, just calling a function "main" does not give it any special semantics.

First, you need to make `main` accessible from outside the class. You do this by making it public.

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Template");
    new Template().menu();
}
```

Then, in your `switch` statement, you can call this static method by using the class name, not creating a new instance.

```
switch (select)
{
    case 1: 
        Template.main(null);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Bad choice!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: just a question: If I want for example return to the main menu? So in the menu of the Program class from Template? how I can I do that?

Comment: @SevengamesXoom I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: for example: `Program` class have a menu, if I press 1 I go into the `Template` class that have another menu. Now in the `Template` class there is also a 0 choice with "go back to main menu", so I want redirect the user to the `Program` class with the main menu. It's clear?

Comment: @SevengamesXoom Unfortunately the answer would be too long for a comment. And you should try figuring it out on your own, it will be an excellent exercise and you'll learn a lot in the process ;)